# bash: Source: command not found

Tags: bash

I keep getting the following error when I open my terminal. I am running Fedora 19.

bash: Source: command not found

The above error also caused my screen to go blank when I tried to login. I then renamed by .bashrc and .bash_profile files, and the system came up fine. So it seems the problem may be with one of these files, but I am unable tell what it is.

Here are my bashrc and bash_profile files:

```
[gmahan@localhost ~]$ cat .bashrc
# .bashrc

[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions

[gmahan@localhost ~]$ cat .bash_profile
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [-f ~/.bashrc]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem might be. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but could you elaborate. I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. I did reinstall the bash package, but I had no luck.

Comment: it's `source` not `Source`.

Comment: I have printed it exactly as it's displayed on the terminal. I thought about that too, It says "Source:"

Comment: While this error is unrelated to the message indicated, you need to separate the [ command with spaces: `[ -f ~/.bashrc ]`. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/134472 .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is caused by the following line:

```
Source global definitions
```

It's probably not a command, but a comment. Prepend a `#` to the line and the error should be gone.

```
# Source global definitions
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Should have seen that, I was messing around with the file on vi the other day. Anyway, thanks a bunch.