# Bash error: missing [: missing `]'

Tags: bash, shell-script

I an writing simple script in Bash, to check Linux file system disk usage on root file system and display a warning message if system is greater than 6%.

The commands are running in a terminal, however when I tried the `if` statement, I am getting this error on line 16 
`[: missing`]'`

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3
  4  
  5 clear
  6 #checking for usage on the system and saving in a file usage1
  7 df -h / >usage1
  8
  9 #display current use to the screen
 10 clear
 11 echo
 12 awk '$5>6' usage1
 13
 14 #Creating variable to use in the awk if statemant
 15 usage2= "awk '{print $5}'/home/peters/usage1 | tail -n1 |cut -c1"
 16 #Building statemant
 17 if ($usage2>6)
 18 print "Warning file system greater than 6% !!"
 19
 20 exit 0
```

Comment: Line 15 should read: `usage2=$(awk blah blah)`, and line 17 `(( usage2 > 6 ))` and if you open an `if` you require a `fi` to close it...

Comment: Are the files `usage1` and `/home/peters/usage1` the same file? I assumer they are (but I'm not sure.. it is a bit odd either way) -- It seems that you can check it in one line: `[[ -n $(df -h / | awk 'int($5)>6{print $5}') ]] && echo "Warning file system greater than 6%"`

Comment: Yes usage1 and /home/peters/usage1 is the same file. I did experience problem on the so I am trying full path to the file.

Comment: @Peter.O  Yes this line works --  [[ -n $(df -h / | awk 'int($5)>1 {print $5}') ]] && echo "Warning file system greater than 6%" ---- Thank you very mutch :)

Comment: Asked twice by the same guy http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218542/50557

Comment: There are so many errors .... 1.-Line 12 change to `usage="$( awk '($5+0>6){print $5}' usage1 )"` Force numerical value by adding 0. 2.- Change line 13 to `echo "$usage"`. 3.- Comment line 15. 4.- Change line 17 to `if [[ $usage -gt  6 ]]; then`. 5.- The command `print` does not print values, echo does. change line 18 to `echo "Warning file system greater than 6% !!"`. Add line 19: `fi`.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134472/ .

Answer (score 3):

Your line 17 should be:

```
if [ $usage2 -gt 6 ]
```

You need to put a space after `[` and before `]`.  Also, when comparing numbers, you should be using `-eq`, `-ne`, `-gt`, `-lt`, `-ge`, and `-le` rather than the familiar symbols.

Comment: Don't use [   ] use [[ ]]. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32210/using-single-or-double-bracket-bash

Answer (score 2):

You want (without any spaces around the `=`)

```
usage2=$(awk '{print $5}' /home/peters/usage1 | tail -n1 |cut -c1)
```

to put into the `usage2` variable the output of your `awk`...`|cut -c1` command. You need a space between the `awk` braced command and its input file name (but no spaces around `=`). BTW, you could simply use [cut(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) as `cut -f5` (instead of `awk '{print $5}'`...) to get the 5<sup>th</sup> field.

BTW, you don't need any `usage1`, you could probably just code

```
usage2=$(df | cut -f5| tail -n1 | cut -c2)
```

<sup>But I did not test that.</sup>

Then you should use

```
if [ "$usage2" -gt 6 ] ; then
   echo "Warning file system greater than 6% !!" > /dev/stderr
fi
```

to [test(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) - it is often a shell builtin - and deal with empty variables value. Since it is an error message it should go to *stderr*, not *stdout*. And you don't want to use `printf` but `echo` (because [printf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html) deals with `%` specially). Perhaps you want [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) ...

But your approach (asking here, perhaps [twice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218542/error-missig-missing-please-help)) is brittle (and asking twice is rude!). You need to learn more about shells. Read the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/), you won't loose your time. Also, use a good editor for writing your shell script. Some editors (`emacs`) have quite good modes for shells - with syntax coloring that helps! ...

BTW, starting temporarily your script with `#!/bin/bash -vx` would help during the debugging phase. And remove the `clear` commands, you don't want them...

At last, did you consider using [disk quotas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_quota)?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am learning shell scripting and desperate some times.  I will definitely read your suggestion -- advanced bash scripting guide-- good stuff. Posting twice wose a simple error. Did not mean any harm, sorry.

Comment: Then delete your second question... Asking twice *is* rude...

Answer (score 1):

Try writing your if statement like this:

```
if [ condition ]; then
      Stuff here
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help guys, I did fix my scrip howewer same error same line nr 16. Pleas look.

Comment: 1 #!/bin/bash 
5 clear
6 #checking for usage on the system and saving in a file usage1
7 df -h / >usage1
8
9 #display current use to the screan
10 clear
11 echo
12 awk '$5>6' usage1
13
14 #Creating variable to use in the awk if statemant
15 usage2=$ " awk '{print $5}'/home/peters/usage1 | tail -n1 |cut -c1 "
16
17 #Building statemant
18 if [ $usage2 -gt 6 ] ; then
19     echo  "Warning file system greater than 6% !!"
20 fi
21 exit 0

Comment: @PeterRoberts please edit your question to add more information. Comments are hard to read and easy to miss. That said, did you actually change your script following the suggestions here? I see the same syntax errors in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[ -n $(df -h / | awk 'int($5)>6{print $5}') ]] && echo "Warning file system greater than 6%"
```

Comment: Yes your code works with no problems @Peter.O. I did change my script according to you suggestion and works fine. Thanks so much for your help, and professionalism. I did receive a lot of heat for posting my question twice. I did not mean any harm or trying being disrespectful to anyone who help me. I am simply  not familiar with this site and Linux community. I am relay surprise how easy people will discard some one, or quick to post negative remark. Any help or comment  are welcome here and greatly appreciated.