# Checking if something is a file [ -f file ]

Tags: shell-script

I cant make the following check to work

```
for file in `ls -R .`
do
    if [-f $file] ......
```

The fact is that I want this check to match when it finds a `file.gz` (`gzip` compressed file) and it is not working.

Comment: How is it not working? Please provide a concrete example

Comment: any reason not to use `find . -type f -name file.gz` and work with its output?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps if you specified what "it is not working" means, we could help you better.

Anyway, if the output you get is "[-f command not found" then you have to put a space between [ and the inside (`/usr/bin/[` is a full featured command):

```
if [ -f $file ] ...
```

but please be aware that the file might contain spaces or other strange characters, so as the very minimum I'd suggest putting quotes around "$file":

```
if [ -f "$file" ] ...
```

and even better, do not parse `ls -R .` but use `find .` instead

Comment: Note that `[ -f "$file" ]` will also return true for symlinks to regular files (as opposed to `find`'s `-type f` for instance).

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to parse `ls` output. If you want a list of all `.gz` files under a folder and do something to each result, the following is a better idea if you're using `bash` or `zsh` and your `find` supports the `-iname` and `-print0` predicate (like on GNU, Solaris 11 or some BSD systems):

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    echo "found a .gz: $file"
done < <(find . -type f -iname "*.gz" -print0)
```

Comment: Note `find`'s `-type f` will not include symlinks to regular files (contrary to `[ -f`). Use `-xtype f` (GNU specific though) to include symlinks to regular files (well symlinks which you can tell eventually resolve to regular files, like symlinks to symlinks to regular files).

Answer (score 2):

You have three problems.

One problem is that [you need whitespace around the `[ … ]` builtin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134472/brackets-in-if-condition-why-am-i-getting-syntax-errors-without-whitespace).

```
[ -f $file ]
```

Another problem is that the output of `ls -R` is pretty useless. `ls -R` displays file names without the directory part, so unless you do some relatively heavy parsing of the output, you can't use it. The right tool to traverse directories recursively is [`find`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find), which has a different syntax.

The third problem is that you're missing double quotes around variable substitutions. This doesn't completely break the script, only if you encounter file names containing whitespace or `\[*?`. Dealing with these file names is trivial as long as you remember to **always use double quotes around variable and command substitutions**: `"$file"`, `"$(mycommand)"`. For more information, see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

```
find . -exec sh -c '
    if [ "$0" ] …
' {} \;
```

Note that you can use `find -type f` to only execute a command (or print out) on regular files, or (on Linux) `find -xtype f` to also include symbolic links to regular files.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not quite what you asked, but it's common on Unix.

Have you considered perl? Because it lets you `grep` based on all sorts of clever conditions.

E.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $file ( grep { -f } glob ( "*" ) ) {
   print "$file is a file\n";
}
```

`grep` iterates the list that `glob` returns (expands as you would expect in a shell command) and then runs a `-f` test on each, filtering the list accordingly.

You can also compound these tests in all sorts of arbitrary ways (like grabbing values from `stat` etc.)

The reason I'm suggesting it is because it *doesn't* suffer any interpolation/expansion issues where parsing `ls` might.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find` command like so:

```
for file in $(find . -type f -iname "*.gz")
do
  #now if is not needed
  ...
done
```

This will save you from testing for file inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

need to use spaces

```
for i in `ls -R .`; do if [ $i == "file.gz" ]; then echo $i; fi; done
```