# small error but seems annoying

Tags: bash, shell-script

[image]

I have error (command not found). so what is the easy solution and explanation for this error?

Comment: See [Brackets in if condition: why am I getting syntax errors without whitespace?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134472/brackets-in-if-condition-why-am-i-getting-syntax-errors-without-whitespace)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a single-brace implementation of `test`, but missing the whitespace that is required.  You probably have something like

```
echo "Is it morning? Please answer yes or no"
read var
if ["$var" == "yes"]; then
    something
else
    something else
fi
```

The problem is that spaces are required inside of the braces, thus:

```
if [ "$var" == "yes" ]; then
```

For more details on the syntax, read the manual page for `test` with the command `man test`.