# trouble with Else statment in Bash

Tags: shell-script, test

I have this simple code that creates .bak files when I clean, . bak files should be removed when I clean again and there is no . bak it should echo "there's no .bak" but it only executes the if condition.
Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod u+x sources/*
if [ "$1" == "clean" ]
then

    if [ -f `sources/*.bak` ]
    then        
       rm sources/*.bak

    else
        echo "there's no .bak files"
    fi

elif ["" == "$1"]
then

echo "This script makes a backup for each .c or .h file in sources directory"

target_files=`echo -n $(ls sources/{*.c,*.h})`
echo
echo "Starting to backup: $target_files"

for i in $target_files 
do 
  cp "$i" "$i".bak
done

echo
echo "The following backup files were created: `echo -n $(ls sources/*.bak)`"
echo
echo "Done"

fi
```

Comment: I haven't read your whole script but I find several obvious problems: [missing spaces in `elif ["" == "$1"]`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/134472), [missing double quotes around variable expansions, and `target_files` should be an array](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766); [use of `ls` instead of directly using wildcards](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is the line

```
if [ -f `sources/*.bak` ]
```

backticks `` ` `` have a special meaning in bash: they are used to evaluate a command and return its output.

E.g. If your username is *frodl* then

```
if [ -f `whoami` ]
```

will check if there is a file named `frodl`.

So if you write `sources/*.bak`, it will first try to glob the term `sources/*.bak`, but since there are no files in the `sources/` directory with a `.bak` extension, the term will not be expanded. It will then try to run the literal term `sources/*.bak`, which is no valid command (actually you *can* have a file called `sources/*.bak` (a filename with an asterisk at the beginning; shudder!), but it seems that you don't. However, this file would have a `.bak` extension, something we ruled out before.)

If you do have a file `sources/deletemyharddisk.bak`, then the term `sources/*.bak` will expand to that string, and then try to execute it (potentially deleting your harddisk).

So what you need to do is use ordinary quotes.

```
backupfiles=sources/*.bak
if [ "x${backupfiles}" = "xsources/*.bak" ]; then
     echo "no .bak files" 1>&2
else
     echo "there are .bak files"...
fi
```

This will first try to expand the `sources/*.bak` term into the `backupfiles` variable. If there are any bak-files, this will become a string of all filenames; if there are none, this will stay the unexpanded string.
If you then compare the result with the literal (unexpanded) `sources/*.bak` you can tell, whether an expansion took place (because there are matching files) or not.

## a better approach

however, there is little reason to first check if there are files and then delete them.
a simpler approach is to just remove all the files that match a given pattern.
`find` can do that for you:

```
find sources/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.bak" -delete
```

(this will search the first level (`-maxdepth 1`) of the `sources/` directory for files (`-type f`; rather than directories or symlinks or other things), which end in `.bak` (`-name "*.bak"`) and then remove them (`-delete`)

#### Do not parse `ls`

Another issue with your code is

```
target_files=`echo -n $(ls sources/{*.c,*.h})`
for i in $target_files 
...
```

You should [never parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Instead use something like

```
 for i in sources/*.c sources/*h
 do
   #...
 done
```

Comment: No, double quotes don't allow globbing. And if they did, that is if the glob expanded to several arguments to the `[` command, that would break the syntax of the `[` command. You can't use globbing with `[`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas shame on me; no idea what i was thinking; updated (and fixed) the answer...

Comment: The glob is not expanded in `backupfiles=sources/*.bak` either. You'd need an array  and to set nullglob. (`shopt -s nullglob; backupfiles=(sources/*.bak); if [ "${#backupfiles[@]}" -gt 0 ]...`) and then there's a question of whether you want to check if they are regular files (all of them? any of them?) as the OP's `[ -f ]` suggests.

Comment: here (bash-4.4.5) the term `backupfiles=sources/*.bak` is expanded.

Comment: You may also want to point out the other `["" == "$1"]` error.

Comment: No, you  probably tried `echo $backupfiles` (split+glob operator; the glob is expanded upon the variable expansion) instead of `echo "$backupfiles"`.

Comment: Note that to have the equivalent of `[ -f file ]` in `find`, you'd need `-xtype f` (GNU specific) instead of `-type f`, as with `-type f`, you'd miss the symlinks to regular files. For the equivalent of the `*.bak` glob, you'd also need to add a `! -name '.*'` to exclude hidden files (and fix the locale to C to avoid deleting hidden files with invalid characters).