# Nmap check if port is open in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, test, nmap

I want to make a script which will check if a port is open on a server. If not open stay in a while. If open continue. The break conditions is use are if "host is up" is present and not "closed". I assume conenction is ok. The problem is that the grep is not working as expected.

I have tried with following:

```
while true; do
 NMAP=$(nmap -p 1700 router.eu.thethings.network)
 if [[$NMAP | grep "Host is up" -ne ""]] && [[$NMAP | grep "closed" -eq ""]]; then
    echo "connection!!!"
    break
 fi


 echo "waiting for connectiong"
 done
```

I run it on a raspberry pi jessie system.

Comment: For a start, `-eq` and `-ne` are arithmetic operators.  If you want to do string comparisons, you need `=` (`==`) and `!=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `[[$NMAP | grep "Host is up" -ne ""]]` is very far from valid bash syntax. The error messages don't tell you exactly how to fix it, but they are a hint that something is seriously wrong.

- [`[[` *expression* `]]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) requires spaces inside the brackets. See [Brackets in if condition: why am I getting syntax errors without whitespace?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134472/brackets-in-if-condition-why-am-i-getting-syntax-errors-without-whitespace)
- `|` is the pipe operator between commands. It isn't an operator in [conditional expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions). In fact `[[ foo | bar ]]` is parsed as the command `[[ foo` piped into the command `bar ]]`, which doesn't do anything useful.
- The [`-eq` operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) compares integers, but what you put around it aren't integers.

To test whether a string contains a substring, you can *either* use the `==` operator in a conditional expression, *or* a pipe through grep (which doesn't involve a conditional expression). With grep, you're not running `$NMAP` as a command, you want to pass this as input to grep, so you need to `echo` it into the pipe. Pass `-q` to grep since you only care about its return status, not about its output.

```
if echo "$NMAP" | grep "Host is up"  && echo "$NMAP" | grep "closed"; then …
```

With a conditional expression:

```
if [[ $NMAP == *"Host is up"* || $NMAP == *"closed"* ]]; then …
```

Do read [Confused about operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/confused-about-operators-vs-vs-vs/306141#306141) which explains about conditional expressions and how they aren't the only way to test whether a condition is true. Also, read [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: Great explanation and very good reading!

Answer (score 6):

```
nmap -p 1700 router.eu.thethings.network
```

Will print "Host is up" if the hosts network is up and there is nothing listening on the port. Use `nc` instead:

```
if nc -w1 -z router.eu.thethings.network 1700; then
  echo "Port is listening"
else
  echo "Port is not listening"
fi
```

Comment: when i run the
nc -z router.eu.thethings.network 1700
 it does not return. Will it behave different in a script?

Comment: This is due to the way tcp/ip works. If it gets no response then it will resend and eventually timeout after about a minute. You could try a simple ping test before testing the port.

Comment: Add the `-w1` option to `nc` to try the connection for one second. This will let you get a quick failure if the host is not up.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example to display `Host is up` when `grep` success and `Host is down` when `grep` return nothing:

```
NMAP=$(nmap -p 1700 router.eu.thethings.network)
(NMAP$ | grep "Host is up") &>/dev/null && echo "Host is up" || echo "Host is down"
```