# What are some cases that the number of spaces do matter in bash (or other shell) scripts

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have been told that the spaces are important in `bash` or other shell scripts and I should not change the existence of spaces unless I know what I am doing. By "changing the existence" I mean either inserting a space between two non-space characters or removing a space between two non-space characters, e.g. changing `var="$val"` to `var ="$val"` or vice versa. 
I want to ask

**Are there any cases in which using a single space or using multiple consecutive spaces in a shell script makes a difference?**.

(Of course, inserting/deleting a space in quotes makes a difference ,like changing from `echo "a b"` to `echo "a  b"` or vice versa. I am looking for examples other than this trivial example.)

I have come across [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/976804/does-it-matter-how-many-spaces-exist-in-terminal-commands) but that one is about adding and removing spaces between two non-space characters for which I know many examples that it would make a difference.

Any help would be appreciated. Include more varieties of shells if possible.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Outside of quotes, the shell uses whitespace (spaces, tabs, newline, carriage-return, etc) as a word/token separator.  That means:

- Things not separated by whitespace are considered to be **one** "word".
- Things separated by one-or-more whitespace characters are considered to be two (or more) words.

The actual number of whitespace chars between each "thing" doesn't matter, as long as there is at least one.

Comment: Thank you. I can't find any counter example myself. I just want to make sure.

Comment: Bash also considers form feeds and vertical tabs to be whitespace.

Comment: true. i originally wrote '...newlines, etc' and then changed it to explicitly add carriage-returns.  accidentally dropped the 'etc'.

Comment: What if the number of spaces is so large, that the program cannot fit into memory?

Comment: @Worse_Username The whitespace does not have to fit in memory. I just created a 48GB script on a machine with 8GB of RAM and 20GB of swap. It ran just fine. It did take 3 minutes to crunch through all of that whitespace, but in the end it successfully ran an `echo` command with that much whitespace between the command and the argument.

Answer (score 25):

This is probably cheating, but this:

```
rm foo\ bar         # "delete the file named 'foo bar'"
```

is different from this:

```
rm foo\  bar        # "delete the files named 'foo ' and 'bar'"
```

even though the spaces are *not* in quotes. ;-)

More confoundingly, this:

```
rm \
    foo          # "delete the file named 'foo'"
```

is different from this:

```
rm \ 
    foo          # "delete the file named ' ', then run the command 'foo'"
```

even though they *look* identical!

Comment: Even though the spaces are not in quotes, the backslash is functionally similar to form of quoting and I'd put this in the same category as the question's "trivial example". (It is interesting though.)

Answer (score 14):

If we don't talk about the space character (`U+0020`), but **any** whitespace character (`U+0020`, `\n`, `\t`, etc.), then one particular case come to my mind: Here-Documents.

This code (using spaces):

```
cat <<- 'EOF'
<space><space>foo
EOF
```

Will print:

```
  foo
```

But this code (using tabs):

```
cat <<- 'EOF'
<tab><tab>foo
EOF
```

Will print:

```
foo
```

That's because ([as POSIX states](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04)):

> If the redirection operator is `<<-`, all leading <tab> characters shall be stripped from input lines and the line containing the trailing delimiter.

Comment: That is interesting.  I thought about here-documents but did not know the `<<-` operator. Thank you very much.

Comment: here documents are a form of quoted text, not shell code.  shell word-splitting doesn't apply.

Comment: @cas Your comment is correct, but I don't think that the OP restricted their question to shell word-splitting. While word-splitting explains everything that word-splitting does (which is a LOT), I think that this is a good additional answer to the question, "Are there any cases in which using a single space or using multiple consecutive spaces in a shell script makes a difference?"

Answer (score 3):

It also has an effect when writing assignment statements. Like if I say `FOO=xyz` it will create an environment variable named `FOO` with value `xyz`, but if I separate the equals with a space, it will think that I'm invoking a program named `FOO` with the arg `=xyz`. So it does matter when it comes to certain syntax.

Comment: Usually `FOO=xyz` does create an internal shell variable but not an environment variable. You need `set -a` or `export FOO=xyz` for that (i.e. making it part of the environment of non-subshell subprocesses).

Answer (score 1):

I came across a good example of 'space' and thought of sharing here. The following condition doesn't evaluate to true for i being somewhere between 100 and 1000.

```
if [ $i -ge 100 -a $i -lt 1000]; then  <some code here>  fi
```

**Notice a missing space between 1000 and closing square bracket**

But when it is changed to as mentioned below, it works as expected.

```
>  if [ $i -ge 100 -a $i -lt 1000 ]; then  <some code here>  fi
```

Comment: Yes, changing from no space to one or more spaces obviously matters, like e.g. cas's answer above mentions. The test `[ ... ]` [is a regular command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/134472/170373), so this is in principle same as `cp foo bar` vs. `cp foobar`.

Comment: @ilkkachu True, But it's not so intutive in the case I mentioned and what is being mentioned for _cp foo bar_ versus _cp foobar_

Comment: I agree with you, @Maneesh. I think that everybody makes this mistake at least once with `[` or `[[`. I think that it also happens with arithmetic evaluations like `echo $(( 3 + 2 ))`. There are so many languages where it is considered good style to not have spaces inside square braces and parentheses that this can really catch people off guard.