# Convert array into string

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, ksh

I have a string say, `test_var=ab_c_de_fg_.txt`. I need to store `ab_c` in one variable (characters before the 2nd `_`) and `de_fg_` in a second variable (characters after the second `_` and before `.txt`), so these two  variables can be used in further operations.

```
test_var=ab_c_de_fg_.txt

for ((i=0;i<{#test_var};i++))
do
    a[$i]="${var:$i:1}"
done

flag=0
temp=0

while [["$temp" -le "${#test_var}"]]
do
    if a[temp] -eq "_" && flag -eq 0
    flag = 1
    continue
fi

if a[temp] -eq "_" && flag -eq 1
#var1=arr[0] to arr[$(temp-1)]
#var2=arr[$(temp+1)] to arr[#(test_var)]
fi

temp=$((temp+1))
done
```

Please guide me, since I am new to shell scripting. Thanks.

Comment: You mention an array, but there is no array here. And your code is full of errors, don't you get error messages when you try to run this? What is that script supposed to be doing? It doesn't seem to have any relation to what you describe in your question.

Comment: You already got some ready-made answers, but if you want to get that script or any other into even a remotely working condition, I'd suggest starting small, building it in pieces, and testing each piece before proceeding. Some useful that immediately came to mind: https://www.shellcheck.net/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134472/brackets-in-if-condition-why-am-i-getting-syntax-errors-without-whitespace/134476 Also, fix the indentation. Having it messed up makes it really hard to read what the script is doing.

Comment: @terdon, the first loop would create an array made of the individual characters of the variable (if the missing `$` was  added before `{#test_var}`)

Comment: @terdon, ... and there's the general idea of processing the string character-by-character, checking for the `_` separator etc. Looks a bit like what someone might write in C to do that.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, but as you say, the individual characters so not what the OP seems to want.

Comment: @terdon, it looks like they're trying to disassemble the string into an array of individual letters, then loop over that, one item at a time, looking for the separator etc. And then build the final variables from parts of that array. It's a doing it on a lower level than is at all necessary, and full of typos and errors, but the idea is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do what your question asks for in `bash` (and ignoring your code, since I can't understand what you're trying to do with it):

```
$ test_var=ab_c_de_fg_.txt
$ read var1 var2 < <(echo "$test_var" | sed 's/_/ /2; s/\.txt$//')
$ echo "$var1"
ab_c
$ echo "$var2"
de_fg_
```

In a script, that would just be:

```
test_var=ab_c_de_fg_.txt
read var1 var2 < <(echo "$test_var" | sed 's/_/ /2; s/\.txt$//')
```

And you now have `$var1` and `$var2`.

The trick is using `read` to read the two variables. That will split its input on the current value of the environment variable `IFS` (which, by default, is a space a tab and a newline). The `sed` command will replace the 2nd `_` with a space (`s/_/ /2`) and remove the `.txt` from the end of its input (`s/\.txt$//`), so what is passed to `read` will be `ab_c de_fg_.txt`, and because there is a space in the middle, each string is saved in in the corresponding variable.

Comment: Note that it assumes `$test_var` doesn't contain backslashes, SPC, TAB, newline characters and depending on the `echo` flavour is not something like `-n`, `-Een`...

Answer (score 2):

To split a string into an array, you can use the split+glob operator (invoked when you leave a parameter expansion unquoted in list context):

```
test_var=ab_c_de_fg_.txt
root_name=${test_var%.*} # remove extension

IFS=_         # split on _
set -o noglob # disable glob part
array=( $root_name"" ) # split+glob, preserve empty trailing element if any
```

`typeset -p array` would then show something like:

```
typeset -a array=(ab c de fg '')
```

To join elements of an array with the first character (byte in ksh) of `$IFS`, you do `"${array[*]}"`.

So:

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[*]:0:2}" "${array[*]:2}"
```

Would output:

```
ab_c
de_fg_
```

And your two variables could be defined like:

```
first_part="${array[*]:0:2}" second_part="${array[*]:2}"
```