# Command not found error

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash

bonus=0

read -p "Please enter your commission amount(enter a integer value only): " comm

if [$comm -le 200]; then 
    echo "No bonus applicable"
elif [$comm -le 300]; then
    bonus=50
    echo "The bonus applicable is $bonus dollars"
else
    bonus=100
    echo "The bonus applicable is $bonus dollars"
fi

exit 0
```

Whenever I run my codes and reach the second line of the code where I include my commission input, it will state that `[199: command not found]` and 199 is the integer that I decided to input to review my codes.

I seek anyone's kind assistance please.

Comment: Also: [Brackets in if condition: why am I getting syntax errors without whitespace?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134472/brackets-in-if-condition-why-am-i-getting-syntax-errors-without-whitespace)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a whitespace after `[` and before `]`. It should be:

```
if [ $comm -le 200 ]; then
```

and:

```
elif [ $comm -le 300 ]; then
```

Additionally, consider using [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net)
and fix all reported warnings.